# How to adapt tcolorbox with XeLaTex

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox

I have switched to XeLaTex several months ago, and tried today to include a Cisco IOS code with the following parameters ([How to insert code from a Router or a Switch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298276/how-to-insert-code-from-a-router-or-a-switch/298330#298330)), as I was doing before using XeLaTex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{cisco}[1][]{size=fbox, listing only, listing options={style=tcblatex,basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,tabsize=2,language=sh},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{cisco}[title=Example of cisco command]
master#show ip cef 10.200.254.4
10.200.254.4/32, version 44, epoch 0, cached adjacency 10.200.200.2
0 packets, 0 bytes
    tag information set, all rewrites owned
    local tag: 20
    fast tag rewrite with Eth0/0/0, 10.200.200.2, tag imposed {18} via 10.200.200.2, Ethernet0/0/0, 0 dependencies
    next hop 10.200.200.2, Ethernet0/0/0
    valid cached adjacency
    tag rewrite with Et0/0/0, 10.200.200.2, tags imposed {18}
\end{cisco}

\end{document}
```

This produce the same output, which is exactly what I want. However, I have this error:

> Package inputenc Error: inputenc is not designed for xetex or luatex \end{cisco}

What can I do to still use XeLaTex and include Cisco IOS code in my document without any warning/error ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `style=tcblatex` loads `inputenc` automatically.

Remove this key when used with `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{cisco}[1][]{size=fbox, listing only, listing options={basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,tabsize=2,language=sh},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{cisco}[title=Example of cisco command]
master#show ip cef 10.200.254.4
10.200.254.4/32, version 44, epoch 0, cached adjacency 10.200.200.2
0 packets, 0 bytes
    tag information set, all rewrites owned
    local tag: 20
    fast tag rewrite with Eth0/0/0, 10.200.200.2, tag imposed {18} via 10.200.200.2, Ethernet0/0/0, 0 dependencies
    next hop 10.200.200.2, Ethernet0/0/0
    valid cached adjacency
    tag rewrite with Et0/0/0, 10.200.200.2, tags imposed {18}
\end{cisco}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to pass the `inputencoding=utf8` among the `options` of `newtcblisting`. This will pass the option to the `inputenc` package internally which is then redundant for the Xe/Lua LaTeX engines (you get a warning, about it not being necessary, that's it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{cisco}[1][]{size=fbox, listing only, listing options={style=tcblatex,basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,tabsize=2,language=sh,inputencoding=utf8},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{cisco}[title=Example of cisco command]
master#show ip cef 10.200.254.4
10.200.254.4/32, version 44, epoch 0, cached adjacency 10.200.200.2
0 packets, 0 bytes
    tag information set, all rewrites owned
    local tag: 20
    fast tag rewrite with Eth0/0/0, 10.200.200.2, tag imposed {18} via 10.200.200.2, Ethernet0/0/0, 0 dependencies
    next hop 10.200.200.2, Ethernet0/0/0
    valid cached adjacency
    tag rewrite with Et0/0/0, 10.200.200.2, tags imposed {18}
\end{cisco}

\end{document}
```

giving:

[image]

Comment: The `inputenc` package is loaded still then, causing a warning. *cough*

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, but it is then discarded… _atchoo_

Answer (score 5):

You can fool the package `tcolorbox` that `inputenc` is already loaded:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter\@namedef{ver@inputenc.sty}{}\makeatother
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{cisco}[1][]{size=fbox, listing only, listing 
options={style=tcblatex,basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,tabsize=2,language=sh},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{cisco}[title=Example of cisco command]
  master#show ip cef 10.200.254.4
  10.200.254.4/32, version 44, epoch 0, cached adjacency 10.200.200.2
  0 packets, 0 bytes
  tag information set, all rewrites owned
  local tag: 20
  fast tag rewrite with Eth0/0/0, 10.200.200.2, tag imposed {18} via 10.200.200.2, 
  Ethernet0/0/0, 0 dependencies
  next hop 10.200.200.2, Ethernet0/0/0
  valid cached adjacency
  tag rewrite with Et0/0/0, 10.200.200.2, tags imposed {18}
\end{cisco}

\end{document}
```

[image]