# Including Cisco IOS commands with proper highlighting in my document

Tags: listings, minted, code

**The problem**

I want to include Cisco IOS commands (from the Cisco IOS CLI) with proper highlighting in my document.

**Is it really necessary?**

One could argue that applying syntax highlighting to Cisco IOS configuration commands is somehow unorthodox, or even unnecessary since command line interfaces are usually presented as plain text. In [Syntax Highlighting For Network Engineers on DevNet Code Exchange](https://blogs.cisco.com/developer/syntax-highlighting-on-code-exchange), this issue is addressed.

**Already existing solutions**

So, I did my research on the already available options in order to avoid reinventing the wheel. I didn't find much.

- In our community I found only a few threads, mainly trying to address the issue using the `listings` package:

  1. [How to insert code from a Router or a Switch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298276/how-to-insert-code-from-a-router-or-a-switch).
  2. [Syntax highlighting of (Cisco) terminal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439892/syntax-highlighting-of-cisco-terminal)

  However, all the proposed solutions are far from complete.
- I came across a custom solution: [Cisco Language for LaTeX Listings Package, by Judson Bishop](https://chainringcircus.org/2020/12/31/cisco-language-for-latex-listings-package/) that also uses the `listings` package.
- I investigated if the `minted` package provides a solution. As you may know, `minted` uses `pygment` highlighter which provides support for a [wide range of languages](https://pygments.org/docs/lexers/) but unfortunately not for Cisco IOS Commands.

**For a long-term, complete solution**

I would like to ask if anyone knows any already available solution for my problem (besides writing my own `listings` language definition). If not, I would love to hear your thoughts on what should I do for a long-term and more complete solution. Is it worth it to write my own lexer on top of an existing one and use it with the `minted` package?